# Javascript causing virus warning and blocking website

Tags: javascript, php

I have a short url script and have been testing various methods of performing the redirect... One method includes redirecting the visitor to a small JS snippet which then forwards them on to the desired web page. However it is being picked up by Kaspersky virus scanner as a trojan HEUR:Trojan-Downloader.Script.Generic it says 'Download Blocked'.

I have seen this method used on a 3rd party website and it works fine.

I'm confused why it is saying download blocked when it is not a download. The header is set to `text/html;charset=UTF-8`

```
<script>
   var u='http:\/\/domain.co.uk\/r\/short&sc=1';
   var l='loca' + 'tion'
   window[l].replace(u);
</script>
```

Why would this JS cause a virus warning? Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: Serving a webpage is basically *"download page from server to user's machine and view on a browser"*.

Answer (score 7):

Because you wrote it to look like a virus.

Obfuscating the destination and property access like that is entirely unnecessary and commonly done by malicious software to make reading and noticing the ill intent more difficult.

Just use `window.location.href = 'http://domain.co.uk/r/short&sc=1';` and you should be in a much better position.

Obfuscating this has no benefit, since the user will know where they're being redirected to anyway. You don't need to use a string accessor for the `location` property (which, btw, [is actually read-only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location)) or escape forward slashes.

If you're redirecting users to this script, it won't actually work, since you need a page wrapping it. You can solve that by replacing your redirect with a redirect straight to the destination (sensible and fairly simple) or a function that calls the snippet:

```
<button onclick="redirect();">Forward Me!</button>

function redirect() {
  window.location.href = 'http://domain.co.uk/r/short&sc=1';
}
```

You could also use a server-side redirect of some sort in your Apache or Nginx configuration, which plays nicely with click-tracking and load balancing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.. However, i still don't understand why a non malicious site would use this? Here is an example: http://api.shopstyle.com/action/apiVisitRetailer?id=480241725&pid=uid4481-24735441-69 view the source code of this through http://www.generateit.net/seo-tools/source-viewer/ They are using it to presumably to hide the affiliate link.. I don't get a virus warning with this site... i'm essentially doing the same thing.